# PYTHON : What i draw in my canvas is unpexpectedly cleared when i call canvas.bind to listen for the keyboard

Tags: python, tkinter, bind, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to use this code to display an changing image on a background:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from pynput import keyboard
import time


def DeclareVariable():

    # I create a background with a 0 displayed at the center
    gobal fenetre
    fenetre = Tk()
    gobal Background 
    Background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Background.png"))
    gobal BackgroundSize 
    BackgroundSize = Image.open("Background.png").size
    gobal canvas 
    canvas = Canvas(fenetre, width=PITLayoutSize[0], height=BackgroundSize[1])
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=Background)
    canvas.create_image(130, 150, image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("0.png")), tag="uniteTag")


def Main():
    global currentStage
    currentStage = 0
    global nbMovers
    nbMovers = 0

    def on_press(event):
        # When the user press 1 i increment a var and call load_image to update the number displayed on the background
        global currentStage
        if event.char == '1':
            currentStage = currentStage + 1
            print(currentStage)
            load_image()

    def load_image():
        # In this function i load the png with the right number depending on the value of the incremented var
        print(currentStage)
        unite = currentStage % 10
        etagePNG = "{}.png".format(unite)

        # I load the picture
        etageTK = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(etagePNG))
        etageC = canvas.find_withtag("uniteTag")
        if not etageC:
            print("Canvas introuvable ?!")
        else:
            # I update the item
            canvas.itemconfigure(etageC, image=etageTK)

        # I update the canvas
        canvas.update()

    # I bind my function to <Key> event
    canvas.bind("<Key>", on_press)

    # Focus on the canvas so he can receive keyboard event
    canvas.focus_set()

    # Start the main loop of the window
    fenetre.mainloop()

DeclareVariable()
Main()
```

The idea is that when the users presses <kbd>1</kbd>, the `currentStage` should increase and a new image is drawn to replace the old one. I use `canvas.bind` to listen for key presses.

However, somewhere between `canvas.update` and `canvas.bind`, the image seems to disappear.

How can I ensure the previous number is still displayed while waiting for a key press? I was unable to solve the problem by using `kynput`. I tried adding `time.sleep` calls to the code to try to locate the problem, but wasn't able to figure anything out.

Comment: That can't be your code.  Are there `global` statements in `DeclareVariable` that are missing?  And you should not be calling `Tk` every time.  You should create one window and keep using it.

Comment: Yes i simplify the code to make it simple to read,i wrongly erased the global declaration of the variables lol,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @TimRoberts,

I handled the TK in the DeclareVariable function and stop used it oon the main looop and it worked,
Here is my final code :

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from pynput import keyboard
import time


def DeclareVariable():

    # I create a background with a 0 displayed at the center
    gobal fenetre
    fenetre = Tk()
    gobal Background 
    Background = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Background.png"))
    gobal BackgroundSize 
    BackgroundSize = Image.open("Background.png").size
    gobal canvas 
    canvas = Canvas(fenetre, width=PITLayoutSize[0], height=BackgroundSize[1])
    canvas.pack()
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=Background)
    canvas.create_image(130, 150, image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("0.png")), tag="uniteTag")

    # I generate my pictures here
    global etageTK
    etageTK = []
    for i in range(10):
        currentTK = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("{}.png".format(i)))
        etageTK.append(currentTK)  # ajoute la sous-liste remplie à la liste principale


def Main():
    global currentStage
    currentStage = 0
    global nbMovers
    nbMovers = 0

    def on_press(event):
        # When the user press 1 i increment a var and call load_image to update the number displayed on the background
        global currentStage
        if event.char == '1':
            currentStage = currentStage + 1
            print(currentStage)
            load_image()

    def load_image():
        # I just load here the correct picture
        unite = currentStage % 10
        etageC = canvas.find_withtag("uniteTag")
        canvas.itemconfigure(etageC, image=etageTK[unite])

        # I update the canvas
        canvas.update()

    # I bind my function to <Key> event
    canvas.bind("<Key>", on_press)

    # Focus on the canvas so he can receive keyboard event
    canvas.focus_set()

    # Start the main loop of the window
    fenetre.mainloop()

DeclareVariable()
Main()
```